# Unknown Error Pops up While installing Oracle Database 11g R2

Tags: 16.04, oracle, database

any one can Help me i faced many error while installing Oracle 11g R2 
and solved them all but this one don't know what to write to search for solution

*using ubuntu 16.04

[here is the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwP24.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are logs for the installer on each attempt in your defined TEMP directory, most of the time it's in /tmp

Check the log contents and provide relevant error messages.